# java MD5 encryption minus value in byte array

Tags: java, encryption, arrays, md5, message-digest

Hello I am using below code to encrypt a string.
I found MD5 make working in -127 - +128 values.

I am getting value in minus for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String message = "smile";

        encrypt("Jack the Bear");
    }

    public static void encrypt(String password) throws Exception {

      byte byteData[] =null;

     MessageDigest md = null;
       try {
         md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md.update(password.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      byteData = md.digest();
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteData));


    }
```

My Output : [101, 23, 66, 106, 91, -51, 6, 119, -13, 23, -101, 108, -122, 27, 20, -124]

Real output : [101, 23, 66, 106, 91, 205, 6, 119, 243, 23, 155, 108, 134, 27, 20, 132]

Comment: *All* Java bytes are signed. It has nothing to do with MD5 specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `byte` type in Java (like almost all other types) is signed, which means it has a range of `-128..127`.

If you want to convert this range to an unsigned range (`0..255`), do this:

```
byte b = -2;
int i = b & 0xff;
```

Print your result `byteData` like this:

```
for (byte b : byteData)
    System.out.print((b & 0xff) + " ");
```

If you want to print the result in hexadecimal format:

```
for (byte b : byteData)
    System.out.printf("%02x ", b);
```

Comment: Rather use hex instead of decimal. You'll never see a hash in decimal format anyway.

Comment: @Kayaman Agree, but the asker has the "real" output in decimal, that's why I suggested this to mach the expected result.

Comment: Yup, I just put the comment here for additional reference or so.

Comment: this output arrya is for C# output

Answer (score 2):

Your digest is computed correctly, there's nothing wrong with negative byte values.

Byte type in Java has range from -128 to +127 which might be somewhat surprising - many people assume that byte is unsigned, but Java doesn't have unsigned number types.

Comment: Almost. Java's only unsigned type is `char` (I know, it doesn't really matter since you won't be doing any calculations with char).

Comment: @Kayman Well, I don't consider char to be number type (box type Character doesn't implement java.lang.Number after all), even though it has ordinal value.

Comment: True, you did specify "unsigned **number** types". Well, semantics semantics.